# Dim variable if not already dim’ed in VBScript / Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Let me start off by saying that I hate VBScript/ASP and don’t know much about it, but I’m forced to work with it, so bear with me, please. :-)

I have a fairly simple page which can either be called directly or virtual-included in other pages. Let’s call this page *included.asp* and say that it may be included in *main.asp*.

*included.asp* uses a variable, an array, which it should inherit from *main.asp* if it can, but which I will define in *included.asp* itself if it’s being called directly.

So somewhere on *main.asp*, there will be something like:

```
Dim myVar(10)
myVar(1) = "Some content here"
```

The obvious way (to me) to then define the variable in *included.asp* if it’s not present to inherit would be something like this:

```
If IsEmpty(myVar) Then
  Dim myVar(10)
  myVar(1) = "Some content here"
End If
```

But this doesn’t do me much good. I get an error 800a0411 “Name redefined” on the line in *included.asp* where I try to `Dim` the variable ‘again’. I’ve since tried with `If VarType(myVar) < 8000` (since arrays [have a VarType value of > 8192](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/3kfz157h%28v%3dvs.84%29); outputting its VarType when the page is included gives 8194) and `If Not IsArray(myVar)` instead, with the same result.

Now, I don’t know if this is a compiler error or a runtime error (nor do I know how to tell the difference in VBScript), but since the error gets thrown inside an `If` block which should (?) never be executed when `myVar` is defined, I’m guessing it’s a compiler error. [This Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/2z84dwk8%28v%3dvs.84%29) calls it (error 1041) a *syntax error*, which I guess means it’s at least thrown at compile-time, not at runtime.

So if it is indeed a compiler error, and it’s not possible to `Dim` the same variable name more than once *anywhere* in VBScript code—regardless of whether the actual `Dim` statement can ever potentially be executed more than once—then how does one handle a situation like this?

#### How can I test whether a variable has already been `Dim`’ed, and then `Dim` it only if it hasn’t?

Comment: Why not just use a different variable in included.asp everywhere you want to display it and assign its value to myVar when it has a value?

Comment: @mjw I suppose I could do that, but it feels like an ugly and messy hack. The included file includes other files, some of which are also included in different files. I don’t know offhand if any of these other included files depend on `myVar`, but they could… in which case, I’d have to check in those files whether `myVar` or `myOtherVar` is set, potentially creating a _third_ variable for the same thing. I’d very much like to avoid that.

Comment: Fair enough. If you must redimension an array, you can use `ReDim myArr(size)` and I believe it will fly even if you never Dimension the array to begin with...however, if you `ReDim preserve` (keeps original contents of array), I think it may complain so test it out and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: yes, includes are not an asp feature, but rather an IIS feature. IIS merges the pages together and after that passes the total result to the ASP processor. That's why the DIM is seen twice. That's also why you can't do a conditional include with an if statement. Look into WSC's for conditional reuseable ASP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I avoid doing stuff like this for the very reason you're running into. There aren't a lot of good options to give you the flexibility you'd like to have.

Suggestion 1 would be to refactor the code so that the included file does not depend on any global variables. Maybe pass the array as a parameter to a function in the included file. Along with doing this, adopt a policy of never creating those dependencies in the future. :-)

Suggestion 2a would be to require that any page that includes *included.asp* must `dim` the globals that it expects (no good way to enforce that; maybe just a big comment at the top of the file). To fix the case where *included.asp* is used directly without being included somewhere else, create another file, say *included_standalone.asp*, which declares the required globals and includes *included.asp*. Use the new *included_standalone.asp* everywhere you used to use *included.asp* by itself.

Suggestion 2b is similar: Move the contents of *included.asp* into another file, say *included_contents.asp*, and change *included.asp* so that it declares the globals and includes *included_contents.asp*. Then change everywhere you used to include *included.asp* and include *included_contents.asp* after declaring and initializing the globals.

ASP isn't that bad once you accept its limitations. If you try to turn it into something it's not, you just come out frustrated. :-)

Comment: Suggestion 1 is unfortunately not feasible here (there are about 10,000 files scattered around a mind-numbingly illogical file system, and I have no idea how many files call this file), but there are only a few places where the file is used as a standalone file, so suggestion 2a is an excellent and elegant solution that I had somehow completely boxed myself out of thinking about! A great example of how thinking too narrowly about a specific problem can prevent you from seeing an obvious solution located just outside the box.

Comment: I don't know if it is a good thing or a bad thing that I have gotten good at thinking this way from using ASP. :-) I inherited a bunch of badly implemented ASP code at an e-commerce site about 20 years ago and I'm in it a couple times a month; maybe two or three times a year to make major changes. I had never counted the files; it looks like about 1500. I edit on my Mac and my source code management system (Vault) keeps the copy on the site current. I can do searches across all my files with my editor (BBEdit) so that's how I would find everywhere "included.asp" is used. :-)

Comment: Basically same here: e-commerce site inherited from a previous developer. About 80 GB of files in total (a mixture of code files and metric shit-tons of PDFs and images), located only on a remote server with no code management system at all, and I haven’t wanted to download everything to my Mac—I don’t have enough HD space left for that! So unfortunately, global search is somewhat impractical. :-/